# ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings returns extra connection string from machine.config

Tags: c#, string, collections, connection

I'm writing a windows service and I need the list of all connection strings defined in App.config.

I Used System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings to get all connections.

it always return this extra connection:

data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true

that I think is added in machine.config.

my App.config is:

```
<add name="AvmPortalConnectionString"
    connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=AvmPortal;Integrated Security=True"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Is there anyway that I can get only connection Strings defined in App.config(not the one in machine.config)

I can remove this, but I wonder if there is a cleaner way!

Thanks

Comment: Possible [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3781928/799558)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try adding a clear before the add:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <clear />
    <add name="AvmPortalConnectionString"
        connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=AvmPortal;Integrated Security=True"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: I totally forgot about <clear/>! thanks :)

Comment: Thanks, I was facing the similar issue without <clear/>.