# Move ConnectionString to App.config

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, app-config

In my WPF-Application I want to connect to a database.

If I use the following code it just works fine:

```
string connectionString = @"Data Source=SERVER\ENGINE;Initial Catalog=MyDb;User ID=sa;Password=123456;";
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
connection.Open();
```

Now I moved the `ConnectionString` to my `App.config` and want to use from there with the following code:

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[0].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
connection.Open();
```

Now I get an `SqlExecption`:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)

The `App.config` looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
  <connectionStrings >
    <add connectionString="Data Source=SERVER\ENGINE;Initial Catalog=MyDb;User ID=sa;Password=123456;" name="connection"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Why does this not work?

Comment: have you debugged to see what `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[0].ConnectionString` actually returns? also take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15015892/configurationmanager-connectionstrings-returns-extra-connection-string-from-mach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:- (Prefer Names instead of index)

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connection"].ConnectionString;
```

You can read why we should [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828060/c-sharp-configuration-manager-connectionstrings).

Answer (score 1):

You can always get the connection string by its name parameter:

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connection"].ConnectionString;
```

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms178411(v=vs.100).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1