# Connection strings and configuration manager

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, sql-server-2005, connection-string

I have a project by someone else and there is this line of code:

```
ConnectionStringSettings myConnectionStringSetting = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[0];
```

which for some reason returns this:

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[0] is returning {data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true}                System.Configuration.ConnectionStringSettings
```

I don't have selexpress installed to my knowledge and my web.config points to my server using a different connection string.  Where do I find the list of all the connection strings in VS 2010?

Doing an find on the entire solution returns no results for sql express either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just try to insert an **<clear/>** tag before your ConnectionsString.

```
 <connectionStrings>
  <clear/>
  <!--You connectionString go here-->
 </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Is that what clear does? It cleans all the connection strings and makes connectionstring["0"] be the one right after clear?

Comment: @chris The clear tag clean the default connectionString which is : source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true

Answer (score 0):

[About Connection Strings and Configuration Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494.aspx)

[About Connection Strings & the Web.config File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178411.aspx)

Example from MSDN:

```
System.Configuration.Configuration rootWebConfig =
            System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("/MyWebSiteRoot");
        System.Configuration.ConnectionStringSettings connString;
        if (rootWebConfig.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings.Count > 0)
        {
            connString =
                rootWebConfig.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["NorthwindConnectionString"];
            if (connString != null)
                Console.WriteLine("Northwind connection string = \"{0}\"",
                    connString.ConnectionString);
            else
                Console.WriteLine("No Northwind connection string");
        }
```

Comment: Sorry, but you should know that a link only answer is not considered a good answer also if the link contains the answer for the OP. Links die and your answer becomes useless to future readers. Try to elaborate or just write a comment.

Comment: The problem is I have a SQLEXPRESS connection string when I debug but it appears no where in the solution or in the web.config. The web.config is the correct one.

Comment: It's much pretty to use name as key to access it:
ConnectionStringSettings connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[name];

Also you may look this question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781928/configurationmanager-keeps-getting-machine-config-connection-string)